# How to log rejected messages in Postfix

Tags: smtp, postfix, log-files

Just gone live with a new Postfix mail server, sat in front of an Exchange box for inbound mail only.

It's set up to reject email for unknown recipients, which works fine, but I want to get a log of exactly what destination email addresses have been rejected, just to be sure no domains/recipients have been missed.

I've had a Google but come up blank. Is there a decent simple way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[pflogsumm.pl](http://jimsun.linxnet.com/postfix_contrib.html) is a great application to parse and produce
statistics from postfix log files.

Comment: Use it on 2 x MX Proxy servers (similar to your config) and has a number of good knob defaults (I mostly use the daily summary log.) p.s. Postfix works well as an outgoing proxy as well as the incoming that you're using it for now.

Answer (score 3):

there are few tools that might help - http://www.postfix.org/addon.html#logfile

but the first step would be to check mail log, /var/log/mail.log or in similar directory, depending on how you have configured it and there you should see NOQUEUE: reject: lines with the information you need.

good luck!
m