# Web Software to monitor e-mail server?

Tags: php, email, web-server, monitoring, smtp

I'm quite sure I'm not the first guy who asks this but I haven't found any response with my bro' Google.

Basically, we have a registration page and we'd like to monitor all the e-mails that are sent via our server, so that if an e-mail is refused by a third-party server we can manually see that the user e-mail address does not exist or that its provider rejects our e-mails.

Of course we have the logs but it's quite complicated when you have a registration every 5 seconds.

So I'm looking for something that is web based (a simple PHP interface ? or even a JAVA servlet) that would list all e-mails sent and whether they have been received, rejected etc.

This would allow a support representative to manually monitor e-mails.

Comment: In which language is written your Web Software, as you call it ? And also it depends on which mail server you use (postfix, sendmail, exchange,...). Please specify it.

Comment: Usually we're on PHP but we don't mind installing Tomcat just to run a servlet. We're on postfix but what we need is some kind of advanced log reader that could optionally work with a database to store old logs dynamically.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to log rejected messages in Postfix](http://serverfault.com/questions/20401/how-to-log-rejected-messages-in-postfix)

Comment: @mailq gave you a good answer, but note that it only gets you as far as "my mail server says someone else accepted it" -- Just because a remote server accepted your message doesn't mean it got delivered to the client's mailbox; Just because it hit their mailbox doesn't mean their MUA didn't declare it spam; and just because it made it to their screen doesn't mean they read & understood it.  (also, any "monitoring " that relies on "a support representative" doing anything "manually" is inherently broken :-)

Comment: @voretaq7 Did I say something different? You also need to look at RFC 6449.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pflogsum.pl from here: http://jimsun.linxnet.com/postfix_contrib.html

It should be an easy task to call it regularly via cron and redirect the outputto a file for a webserver. With a little magic you could even call it via CGI.

If you are a PHP/Perl magician you can even pretty print into a HTML page.